# HTTP request VBA code to Python not working

Tags: python, vba, pandas

I can't convert this VBA code for some reason. I keep getting a 401 or a 400 status when running the Python script. This VBA code works fine and gets the required token

```
Dim user
Dim pwd
Dim url
Dim response
Dim sessionid


url = "https://xxxx"

sRequest = "{""itrent"": {""login"": {""user"": ""xxx"",""pwd"": ""xxx""}}}"

response = HTTPPost (url, sRequest)

sessionid = ""
If InStr(response,"sessionid") > 0 Then

sessionid = getSession(response)
Else
MsgBox "No Session received : " + response
End If

MsgBox response

Function HTTPPost(sUrl, sRequest)
set oHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
oHTTP.open "POST", sUrl,False
oHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/plain"
oHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(sRequest)
oHTTP.send sRequest
HTTPPost = oHTTP.responseText
End Function
```

my code is for python trying to convert from the VBA script:

```
import urllib
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import ssl
import requests
import json
from itertools import chain
import timeit
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import numpy as np
import datetime
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth


# Todays Date
d = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
TOKEN_API_URL = 'https://'
sRequest = "{""itrent"": {""login"": {""user"": ""xxxx"",""pwd"": ""Pxxx""}}}"
session = requests.Session() 
session.headers = {'Accept':str(len(sRequest)), 'Content-Type':"text/plain"}
    # data = urlencode(payload).encode()

login = session.post(TOKEN_API_URL,data=json.dumps(sRequest))
 print(login)
```

Comment: Can you try sending it without the `Accept` content-length header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try the following formulation. Note that " doesn't need escaping; Use outer single quotes.

```
import requests

TOKEN_API_URL = 'https://xyz'
data = '{"itrent": {"login": {"user": "xxx","pwd": "xxx"}}}' 
headers = {'Content-Length':str(len(data)),'Content-Type':'text/plain'} 

r = requests.post(TOKEN_API_URL, headers = headers, data = data)
print(r)
```

Comment: Still doesn't work I have tried that again. this is where I started! very frustrating!

Comment: that's ok. What is the stack trace? Can you pastebin.com it? And did you try with the alternate header in the comment? Remove personal info of course.

Comment: Also, is there API documentation provided?

Comment: This is the API documentation. They have a mixture of SOAP API with poor documentation and the same with the REST API. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6rUW3CgX3YHUjdiTFV4aW9UR1pVVUNBdm95UHZ5VUJTNTZz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: what happened with using the json header?

Comment: I tried with that header and the additional - such a pain

Comment: so you swopped out to use the json header instead and still failed?

Comment: wow this worked with your settings = headers = {'Content-Length':str(len(data)),'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}

Comment: Also, I am skimming the web services documentation and I am not seeing anything about APIs. Is that right? Furthermore, it looks like you can manually access a GUI to use services which might mean you can capture the http request in dev tools as curl and then translate that direct to python.

Comment: unbelievable this isn't in the documentation! Now to work out the SOAP APIS! any idea where to start!!

Comment: Cool. Updated answer. Main thing was to use the right pairing of key values and to not double up on the ". With respect to SOAP (blurgh......) see my comment above about not seeing anything in that documentation but if there is a GUI then use fiddler to capture the traffic.

Comment: thank you will try that - thank you so much for your help.

Comment: No worries. Pleasure :-)